# Core Data to-Many relationship NSPredicate to fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have to fetch all books having tags that selected book has.

```
BOOK <<-->> TAGS
```

A book can have multiple tags. 
If suppose i select a book and that has tags "database, algorithms".
Then it should select all books that has tags "database", "algorithms", and both "database, algorithms".

My Predicate to fetch from core data is :

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY %K IN %@)",
                         REL_BOOK_TAG_LIST, tagList];
```

where tagList is of selected book's tagList (of type `NSSet`). I also tried using `NSArray` but didn't work.
I am going in correct direction of should have to do something differnt?
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did you get an error or wrong results? Please describe the problem more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags IN %@", tagList]];
```

That should work is tagList is an array of actual `Tag` objects and `tags` is the `relationship` name from `Book` to `Tag`.

Comment: That's the exact same predicate as in the question.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have the brackets but I've used the same predicate many times and it has worked for me. Will wait for the OP to explain WHY it isn't working and edit if necessary.